# Not able to paste values which are separated by enter in textarea of jqgrid version 4.4.3

Tags: jqxgrid

This is my code

```
$("#list").jqxGrid(
 {
{ text: 'Confirm Note', columntype: 'textarea', datafield: 'confirmNote', width: 110,
                  initeditor: function (row, column, editor) {
                        editor.attr('maxlength', 1500);
                    }
              }
}
```

This is creating textarea box.
problem is when i paste certain text inside text box like
This is below text:
TEST 1
TEST 2
TEST 3

then only TEST 1 is entering into textbox,leaving out TEST 2 and TEST 3.

Comment: Do you use `jqxGrid` or `jqGrid` (compare the code with the tag used in your question)? Moreover the code which you posted contains absolutely no information. If you want that other people help you then you should explain more clear what you do currently and were you have a problem.

Comment: I have added code also, am using jqxGrid which creating textarea box, problem is when i paste any text which has \n content it takes only first content leaving out other as i mentioned above.

Comment: If you use `jqxGrid` then you should remove `jqGrid` tag because `jqxGrid` and `jqGrid` are two **absolutely different** software products. Sorry, but I can't help you with `jqxGrid`.